# How to customize MFC MDI CMFCTabCtrl

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, mfc, mdi

I've created MDI application based on MFC framework but the style of `CMFCTabCtrl`'s doesn't satisfy our requirements. I want to change the tab height, colors and add some pictures and buttons.

But I don't know how. Are there any examples or articles that will help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily customize your MFC Tab control. There are plenty of options.

To enable **Close** buttons you just need to call `m_TabControl.EnableActiveTabCloseButton();`

Make sure to add a `WM_CLOSE` message handler in your child window:

```
void CMyTabWindow::OnClose()
{
    CMFCTabCtrl *pTab = static_cast<CMFCTabCtrl*>(GetParent());
    pTab->RemoveTab(pTab->GetActiveTab());
}
```

You can customize colors using `SetTabBkColor()` or `SetAutoColors()`.

You can also set images using `SetImageList()`.

The height can also be customized using `SetTabsHeight()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I find those methods are based on the MDI application framework style. Is there any way to customize the tab control without all of the styles? I want to customize the tab control like draw some rectangles by GDI in the OnDraw method. But I can't overwrite the WM_DRAWITEM message In my child frame class. I have been created my own tab control which derived from the standard tab control class. and put it on the above on MDI client. responding the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message to active the views. But it doesn't the method I want to use.

Comment: If you want complete owner draw solution you will need to re-implement entire control. And also you'll have to create your own MDI frame. I would not recommend doing that. The MS UI standards have been developed by professional designers and have been tested by many users.